# Why with CSV file it loads first column as a dtype64[ns], but a txt as a object

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks to this forum someone else on here I have this code:

```
names=['Date','Wind Speed','Wind Direction']
df2 = pd.read_csv('test_met.csv', index_col=0, names=names, parse_dates=[0])

aethalometer=['Date','Conc']
df1=pd.read_csv('BC_2012_1min.csv', index_col=0, names=aethalometer, parse_dates=[0])
df1=df1[df1['Conc']>-10]

print(len(df1))

print("here")

df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')
df2['per'] = df2.index.to_period('h')
pers = df2.loc[(df2['Wind Direction'] > 340) | (df2['Wind Direction'] < 12) , 'per'].unique()
```

Now with this: I get:

> TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

printing df1.index:

I get:

```
Index(['TimeW_1min', '01/04/2012 00:00', '01/04/2012 00:01',
       '01/04/2012 00:02', '01/04/2012 00:03', '01/04/2012 00:04',
       '01/04/2012 00:05', '01/04/2012 00:06', '01/04/2012 00:07',
       '01/04/2012 00:08',
       ...
       '30/09/2012 23:50', '30/09/2012 23:51', '30/09/2012 23:52',
       '30/09/2012 23:53', '30/09/2012 23:54', '30/09/2012 23:55',
       '30/09/2012 23:56', '30/09/2012 23:57', '30/09/2012 23:58',
       '30/09/2012 23:59'],
      dtype='object', name='Date', length=491589)
```

In this case the csv file looks like: (Originally it was a text file which I resaved as a CSV):

```
TimeW_1min,CONC_1min
01/04/2012 00:00,17.9
01/04/2012 00:01,-1.2
01/04/2012 00:02,16.8
```

Meanwhile if I use the original txt file: I get:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

At which point: df1.index looks like:

```
Index([], dtype='object', name='Date')
```

---

But when I use another dataset that looks like:

```
01-mar-05 12:00,  22.7,  8.1, 0.0214, 1.3727, 0.0214, 1.6969, 1.00,30.603
01-mar-05 12:05, -11.7,  8.1, 0.0214, 1.3725, 0.0214, 1.6965, 1.00,30.5871
```

It not only runs the program, df1.index looks like:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2005-03-01 12:00:00', '2005-03-01 12:10:00',
               '2005-03-01 12:15:00', '2005-03-01 12:20:00',
etc.

 '2005-03-03 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

So how do I convert the first either as a txt or a csv file to be read as a datetime64[ns] format.

Many thanks

here is a link to the original text file: That I am tryign to get the code working for:

http://expirebox.com/download/fe01dc85c38e9bf13d477508006d7c94.html

But this gives a weird format:
So I went into excel and saved it as a csv.., which can be found here:

http://expirebox.com/download/b984ecf365c4c19387a650eeb17f008f.html

The second one is what I am trying to use.. but to no avail

Changed code to:
`aethalometer=['Date','Conc']`
`df1=pd.read_csv('BC_2012_1min.txt', names=aethalometer, parse_dates=True,skiprows=1,sep='\t').set_index('Date')`
`df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')`

Now prints out as:

`2012/9/30 23:58:00   12.40`
`2012/9/30 23:59:00    2.60`

but says:
`AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period`

And df1.index is still an object:

`dtype='object', name='Date', length=491588)`

Tried: 
`df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)`

but that says unknown string format

Comment: I removed the header- in the txt file but that made no difference

Comment: AFAIK this is an outstanding bug in that you can't parse the strings to datetime and specify it as the index, can you try the following: `df2 = pd.read_csv('test_met.csv', names=names, parse_dates=[0]).set_index('Date')`

Comment: KeyError: 'Date' is what I get when trying that:
`df1=pd.read_csv('BC_2012_1min_edited2.csv', index_col=0, names=aethalometer, parse_dates=[0]).set_index('Date')`

Oh and it works for df2 not df1 btw.

Comment: Your index output is a bit weird, it looks like it's parsed the header as the first first element for `df1`: `Index(['TimeW_1min', '01/04/2012 00:00', '01/04/2012 00:01',` can you post the raw data or link to the actual csv/txt file

Comment: The raw data is to big to put on here-is there a way to upload it? Just noticed that there is empty data(when excel) in the second column of the txt file-would that be whats causing it to have an issue? If so do you think that this would be able to cope with Nan data?

Comment: You need to include data and code that others can reproduce here it looks like the empty rows may be causing the issue here, try adding `skiprows=1` as an arg to `read_csv`

Comment: @EdChum

With the CSV saved version of text file came back as 
`TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`
using the original txt:
`TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: With the pandas.read_csv the blank rows would be interpreted as Nans by default. So should be fine?

Comment: sure, you can drop them calling `dropna`, the main thing is to not screw up the header line which determines the column names and the number of columns

Comment: Manually went into the file: and deleted header:
01/04/2012 00:00,17.9
01/04/2012 00:01,-1.2
01/04/2012 00:02,16.8
01/04/2012 00:03,29.8
01/04/2012 00:04,-45
01/04/2012 00:05,-19.8
01/04/2012 00:06,5.7
01/04/2012 00:07,20
01/04/2012 00:08,-23.3
01/04/2012 00:09,61
01/04/2012 00:10,-57
01/04/2012 00:11,21.1
01/04/2012 00:12,16
01/04/2012 00:13,23.6
01/04/2012 00:14,-7.7
01/04/2012 00:15,-15.4
01/04/2012 00:16,-39
01/04/2012 00:17,52



but still get:
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: I'm not sure what you posted but the second entry looks weird `17.9 01/04/2012 00:01` this looks like it's composed of 2 data elements I think you need to look at the initial and parsed structure and clean it up as this has nothing to do with pandas here

Comment: The first column, second column:
01/04/2012 00:00,17.9
second line:
01/04/2012 00:01,-1.2 

Sorry, thats the way its been copied across

Comment: I really can't help you if you don't post raw data and code that others can run to reproduce your errors also update your original question rather than post comments as comments are hidden and formatting gets lost in comments

Comment: Is there a way to share a file: or post a link to it:
As I said its just too big to fully copy across:

Comment: edit the post and add a link

Comment: Their is a link in the question now :)

Comment: That file is tab separated, add `sep='\t'` as an arg to `read_csv`

Comment: As can see in question, changed code as you kindly recomended. 
But how can I make the index be read as a integer not as object?

Comment: Actually it looks like this should just work: `aethalometer=['Date','Conc'] df1=pd.read_csv('BC_2012_1min.txt', names=aethalometer, parse_dates=[0],skiprows=1,sep='\t', index_col=0) df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')`

Comment: Got:
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period' 
:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your file looks like it's been foo-ed by whatever method you've done to create it, you have the header repeated on lines:

43202,  87843, 132482, 174243, 186697, 231338, 274539, 319180, 363821, 407022, 448389

like the following:

```
2012/4/30 23:59:00  -16.00
TimeW_1min  CONC_1min
2012/8/1 00:00:00   15.10
```

So what you can do is to not try to parse the date column and convert using `to_datetime` with params `errors='coerce'` which will convert the erroneous lines to `NaT` you can then filter the rows out and set the index and convert to `PeriodIndex` as desired:

```
In [126]:
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\BC_2012_1min.txt', sep='\t', names=['Date','Conc'], skiprows=1 )
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df = df[df['Date'].notnull()].set_index('Date').to_period('h')
df.index

Out[126]:
PeriodIndex(['2012-04-01 00:00', '2012-04-01 00:00', '2012-04-01 00:00',
             '2012-04-01 00:00', '2012-04-01 00:00', '2012-04-01 00:00',
             '2012-04-01 00:00', '2012-04-01 00:00', '2012-04-01 00:00',
             '2012-04-01 00:00',
             ...
             '2012-09-30 23:00', '2012-09-30 23:00', '2012-09-30 23:00',
             '2012-09-30 23:00', '2012-09-30 23:00', '2012-09-30 23:00',
             '2012-09-30 23:00', '2012-09-30 23:00', '2012-09-30 23:00',
             '2012-09-30 23:00'],
            dtype='int64', name='Date', length=491577, freq='H')
```

So in your case change my first line to this:

```
aethalometer=['Date','Conc']
df1=pd.read_csv('BC_2012_1min.csv', names=aethalometer, sep='\t', skiprows=1)
```

Comment: That's great but this looses all the coonc data

Comment: I don't understand I'm showing the result of the index conversion if you look at `df` it still has `Conc` column

Comment: When I put print df['Conc'] it came up as empty and I did df.to_csv file("djsdhj.csv" and that just had headings...with no data 

`Date,Conc`

Comment: This question is getting tedious as I don't understand what you're trying as when I load your txt file, not the csv file it works using the code I've posted, can you edit your question with updated code and the output from `df.info()`

Comment: Sorry, that is is getting tedius. I really appreciate your help. I reran it, and now the Conc column is no longer empty. (But it was before) Never mind, it all seems good. Once again thank you so much

Comment: Feel like I've asked you enough, 
df=df[df['Conc']>-250]

Claimes the Conc is a string..the final output, I wanted as a number -so can plot a graph

Comment: Try converting to int `df['Conc'] = df['Conc'].astype(int)` if this fails try `df['Conc'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Conc'], errors='coerce')` this may introduce `NaN` values where they are invalid you'll need to see why using `df.loc[df['Conc'].isnull()]` and see which rows in the orig file are duff